# How to force HTML5 and disable Flash in JWPlayer

Tags: javascript, html, jwplayer

Here is my code which should use HTML5 Player while playing video.

```
<html>
<head><script type="text/javascript" src="http://content.jwplatform.com/libraries/asdetr.js"></script></head>

<body>

<div id="myElement">Loading the player...</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

var playerInstance = jwplayer("myElement");
playerInstance.setup({
    file: "http://content.jwplatform.com/videos/trytry-789.mp4",
    image: "http://content.jwplatform.com/thumbs/dfg569-676.jpg",
    width: 640,
    height: 360,
    modes: [
            { type: "html5",

            config: {
              file: "http://content.jwplatform.com/videos/trytry-789.mp4"
                    }
            }
           ]
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please suggest me good way to use HTML5 player. and correct me if I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code. It works for me.

```
<html>
<head><script type="text/javascript" src="http://content.jwplatform.com/libraries/asdetr.js"></script></head>
<body>
<div id="myElement">Loading the player...</div>

<video crossorigin="anonymous" poster="http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/attachments/268150" controls="controls" width="640" height="272">
<source src="http://content.jwplatform.com/videos/C4lp6Dtd-640.mp4" type="video/mp4" />

</video>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be possible, I created this fiddle for you:

https://jsfiddle.net/rdgfuentes/gwa5f438/

One of the things that may cause the problem is that you are including jwplayer from an external site (`http://content.jwplatform.com/libraries/asdetr.js`) that currently is returning 404. I changed it to `http://content.jwplatform.com/libraries/XeGdlzmk.js` and fixed it temporarily; but that not the final solution.

The are two ways of implementing jwplayer in your site depending where are you loading the library from:

- Cloud Hosted player: from jwplayer servers.
- Self Hosted: from your server.

I've always applied the self hosted solution which requires you to download the package and included all of its files on your server.

Here you can find more information about it. http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1772740-dashboard-faq#self-hosted-vs-cloud-hosted

Answer (score 0):

Use this code instead. You are using an modes block which is for JW Player 5 and very deprecated. The code below works because JW6 and JW7 already force the primary rendering mode to be HTML5 anyways.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://content.jwplatform.com/libraries/asdetr.js"></script>
</head>   
<body> 
<div id="myElement">Loading the player...</div>   
<script type="text/javascript">   
var playerInstance = jwplayer("myElement");
playerInstance.setup({
    file: "http://content.jwplatform.com/videos/trytry-789.mp4",
    image: "http://content.jwplatform.com/thumbs/dfg569-676.jpg",
    width: 640,
    height: 360,
    fallback: false
});
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: I have used the above code and it works, but I have one question when we right click on the player it is still showing flash player rather than HTML 5. The video we are using is .mp4 or do we need to any other video format?
Thanks

Comment: Do you have a link? My code, I tested locally, was html5, not Flash.

Comment: This is running in html5 mode for me.

Comment: I am using JW PLayer Version 7.
How to check is JW Player is using HTML5 Player? and Flash Player?
Is there any way to check it?

Thanks.

Comment: Right click the player. If there is is a Flash version in the right click menu, it will say so.